# Ruby on Rails + Michael Hartl tutorial + VPS = issues with AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, nginx, fog

I have finished Michael Hartl tutorial and I'm trying to deploy it with https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-puma-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04. Unfortunately I'm stuck with RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate because it's generating following error:

```
ArgumentError: Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key

/home/me/simpleapp/config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'

/home/me/simpleapp/config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'

/home/me/simpleapp/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>
```

'

I have even copied those files 1:1 and still this error persists. Any idea how could I solve it? I really am tired with trying to fix it with different solutions from web.
Thanks

edit: I am adding my carrier_wave file:

```
if Rails.env.production?
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.fog_credentials = {
      # Configuration for Amazon S3
      :provider              => 'AWS',
      :aws_access_key_id     => ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY'],
      :aws_secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET_KEY']
    }
    config.fog_directory     =  ENV['S3_BUCKET']
  end
end
```

Comment: You need to set your AWS environment variables in production.  Probably your initializer (`carrier_wave.rb`) is expecting `ENV['aws_access_key_id']` and `ENV['aws_secret_access_key']` or something like that to be set in your production environment.

Comment: at some stage I tried to set it everywhere -> I got advice to set it in secrets.yml. But it does not work :/

Comment: Can you update your post with the first 10 lines of your carrier wave initializer?

Comment: I have updated my first post. What I have tried:
Adding these values straight into the file
Adding values to secrets.yml
Adding values to .bashrc

Comment: On your prod machine, try `printenv | grep 'S3'`.  Do you see those three S3 environment variables (`S3_ACCESS_KEY`, `S3_SECRET_KEY`, `S3_BUCKET`)?

Comment: artur@vps:~/simpleapp$ printenv | grep 'S3' gives me nothing

Comment: OK I just hit Post Answer on the answer I wrote, anticipating this.  There are several ways to skin this cat but `dotenv` is pretty slick.  As a stop gap, you can just set these variables locally on your prod server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root issue is that Carrier Wave is expecting your AWS environment variables to be populated but they are not set in your production environment.

I would recommend you look at something like the `dotenv` gem which can find [here](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv).  Environment variable housekeeping in multiple environments can be a real pain so it helps to have a tool to facilitate.  Dotenv (and others like it) provides more of a turn key approach to this.

Note that the recently introduced `secrets.yml` for Rails secret management is a nice step in the right direction, but still requires a bit of code/know how to utilize.

In any event, be very careful about how you manage any files with secrets.  At a minimum, the file should be in your `.gitignore` so that you aren't potentially broadcasting your secrets.

Comment: Ok. I think I got it now. I have to set .env file (env.production?) in root folder of app?. And then from there set all the keys. I added Dotenv::Railtie.load to config/application.rb. I'm reading their webpage and that's what's a little bit unclear to me.

Comment: Install the gem.  Create `~/.env` (yes in the root folder) and set your environment variables there (e.g. S3_ACCESS_KEY=12ABC...).  Restart Rails.  You should still read the doc to understand how you can create separate `.env` files for each environment.

Comment: Yes! I got it in the mean time! Thank you! 
It's pretty good lesson for me!